# Error in cv::imshow

Tags: python

I am trying to run this Python program but it gives an error.
I don't understand what is the error and how to solve it.

#### Error:

```
error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215) 
    size.width>0 && size.height>0 
in function cv::imshow
```

#### Source code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#original img
img = cv2.imread('1.jpeg')
#gray img
img1 = cv2.imread('1.jpeg',0)
#display img
cv2.imshow('img',img)

cv2.imshow('gray img',img1)

#view image size or shape
print (img.shape)
print(img1.size)

#number of pixels
print(img.size)
print(img1.size)
#graph 
"""
x1=[6,2,4,3]
x2=[2,3,4,5]
plt.scatter(x1,x2)
plt.show()
"""

#write an image
cv2.imwrite('gray_image.jpeg',img1)

#access specific index
print(img[150,150])

#modify the pixel value
img[150,150] = 30
print (img[150,150])

#crop image
crop = img[100:150,100:150]

cv2.imshow('cropped image',crop)

#img will display till press the enter
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The error is in line: cv2.imshow('img',img)

Answer (score 1):

The message error means that img hasn't a valid image to show. Make sure that the address '1.jpeg' is valid (same folder, correct file name).

It is a good practice always that you load a resource, like read an image, check if the resource was actually loaded. In that case, you should to check:

```
img = cv2.imread('1.jpeg')
if img is not None
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
```